# Select checkbox where tablerow contains certain text

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, html-table

I have a table with two columns. The first column are all checkboxes and the second a list of attribute names. How do I check the checkboxes next to a table cell that contains certain text?

This is my table:

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td class="SelectColumn"><span title="Select this attribute">
            <input id="chkSelected" type="checkbox" /></span> </td>
        <td>Age (required)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my try with jQuery code:

```
$('#[someButton]').click(function () {
        var tableRow = $("td:contains('required')").closest('td').find('input');
        $(tableRow).attr('checked', true);
});
```

When I debug this code, tableRow.length returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer by  myself :)

```
var tableRow = $("td:contains('required')").prev().find('input');

$(tableRow).attr('checked', true);
```

Is there a more elegant/efficient way to do this?